# How to vertically center the items in the Android Toolbar View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

I have a `Toolbar`, and it seems no matter what I set the height to, the menu items I've added to it remain in the same spot vertically. I'm trying to make the `Toolbar` smaller, and because the items aren't moving, they get clipped when I make the `Toolbar` the height I want it to be. Is there any way to center the menu items vertically in the `Toolbar`?

`Toolbar` src:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="40dp"
         android:background="@color/red">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/search_items"
        layout="@layout/search_items"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Doesn't work:

1. setting android:gravity="center_vertical" for the `Toolbar`

Comment: you can take relative layout in toolbar and then include your layout into relative layout with center in parent property .

Comment: @rayba no. it's the menu items that aren't being centered vertically not the search_items layout i have in it. that layout and its children are all positioned properly

Comment: add your search_items xml, i think that your problem could be related with it

Comment: @JonathanAste what do you mean by add it?

Comment: add the layout code to your post to see it!

Answer (score 0):

Put it inside Linear or Relative Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="40dp"
     android:background="@color/red">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

     <include
        android:id="@+id/search_items"
        layout="@layout/search_items"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```